# Installing 32 bit libraries on x86_64 redhat 6.2

Tags: linux, 32bit-64bit, x86-64, redhat

How can I install 32 bit runtime libraries (e.g. libX11.so.6) on redhat enterprise linux version 6.2? I already have 64 version of these libraries installed on my system.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it like this:

```
yum install xorg-X11-libs.i386
```

Your 32bit applications will take their libs from there, your 64bit applications will stay with their libs.

Comment: I already tried that. I have fontconfig (64 bit package) on my system and I want 32 bit version. I tried yum install fontconfig.i386 and got "No packages found".

Comment: Even I have the same issue. I have been trying to install pysvn 32 bit version library on centOS 6.5. I have followed the steps given in this url https://centos.pkgs.org/6/epel-i386/pysvn-1.7.6-1.el6.i686.rpm.html but 64 bit version pysvn is getting installed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not working and I am using CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core) with Linux 3.10.0-1160.36.2.el7.x86_64